# Link does not pass on id correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

In a view I have included the link:

```
<%= link_to("Upgrade account", upgrade_path(@organization)) %>
```

This link exists on a standard 'show' view/page. So the visitor is already on for example http://localhost/organizations/123 with 123 being the @organization.id. So there is an @organization defined.

In the controller I have:

```
  def upgrade
    @organization = Organization.find(params[:id])   # This is the line that doesn't work
    @actioncode = Actioncode.new
    @amount = DEFAULT_PRICE
    @currency = "EUR"
    @description = @organization.id
    @transaction_description = "MyDescription"
    @transaction_type = "S"
    @hash = hash(@description, @amount, @currency, @transaction_type)
    render 'checkout'
  end
```

However, when I click the link in development in the show view, I get the error message below.

```
No route matches [GET] "/signup/upgrade.123"
```

Does anyone have an idea what is going wrong? You would expect 'upgrade/123' but also if I manually change the address in the browser's address bar to 'upgrade/123' I get the same.

In routes I have:

```
  post 'signup/upgrade'     => 'organizations#upgrade',     as: 'upgrade'
  get 'signup/organization' => 'organizations#new',         as: 'register'
  get 'signup/register'     => 'organizations#new_premium', as: 'register_premium'
  post 'signup/register'    => 'organizations#checkout',    as: 'signup_checkout'
  get 'signup/confirmation' => 'organizations#confirmation'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updating your route to

```
post 'signup/upgrade/:id'
```

You can't test this url from the browser's address bar because that will submit a GET instead of a POST

Answer (score 0):

you have route with `post` and you are trying to get the url with `get`.

btw: use `rake routes` to see your routes